# HTTPRequest and Verbose cURL (curl -vX ...)

Tags: wolfram-cloud, data-acquisition, api

Using CouchDB, Windows 10, M11.3

This curl command works fine at the command line,
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbName

and this works fine with

```
URLExecute@HTTPRequest["http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbName",<|"Method" -> "PUT"|>]
```

Both return {"ok" -> True}, as expected.

How do I make URLExecute@HTTPRequest... return verbose, like curl -vX PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbName does at the command line?

Comment: `RunProcess["curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbName"]`

Comment: thx for the hint.  This works: RunProcess[{"cmd", "/c", "curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbname"}]

Comment: From Mac, anytime I need to make a request and can't figure out the proper Mathematica code, CURL is robust enough where I'm happy enough to just quickly call it directly.

Comment: When I wan maximum "verbosity" I use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see exactly what web request Mathematica is sending and receiving. BTW, I use CouchDB from Mathematica too.

Comment: Thx for the Fiddler suggestion.